# loop to extract text from multiple tags in a <div> tag with a Beautiful Soup parse

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to run a loop in a web scraping script that uses Beautiful Soup to extract data from this [Page](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313&_nkw=%27american%20silver%20eagle%27%201%20oz%20-ruthenium%20-proof%20-preorder%20-ms%20-ngc%20-pcgs%20-anacs%20-lot%20-painted%20-hologram%20-pair%20-capsule%20-capsules%20-holder%20-holders%20-limited%20-tube%20-bar%20-ring%20-set%20-pendant%20-pre-order%20-key%20-date%20-coa%20-roll%20-colorized%20-toning%20-toned&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_udlo=0&_udhi=100&_osacat=0&_odkw=american%20silver%20eagle%201%20oz%20-ruthenium%20-proof%20-preorder%20-ms%20-ngc%20-pcgs%20-anacs%20-lot%20-painted%20-hologram%20-pair%20-capsule%20-capsules%20-holder%20-holders%20-limited%20-tube%20-bar%20-ring%20-set%20-pendant%20-pre-order%20-key%20-date%20-coa%20-roll%20-colorized%20-toning%20-toned&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1). The loop will loop through each div tag and extract 4 different pieces of information. It searches a h3, a div, and 2 span tags. But when I add the ".text" option I get errors from the 'date,' 'soldprice,' and 'shippingprice.' The error says:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I can get the text value from the 'title,' but nothing else when i put ".text" at the end of the line or in the print function. The script overall will extract the correct information when it is run, however I don't want the html tags.

```
results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "s-item__info clearfix"}) #to separate the section of text for each item on the page
for item in results:
    product = {
        'title': item.find("h3", attrs={"class": "s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags"}).text,
        'date': item.find("div", attrs={"class": "s-item__title--tag"}), #.find("span", attrs={"class": "POSITIVE"}),
        'soldprice': item.find("span", attrs={"class": "s-item__price"}),
        'shippingprice': item.find("span", attrs={"class": "s-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost"}),
    }
    print(product)
```

Comment: error shows that it didn't find items. maybe try with simple `class` or even without `class`. I'm not sure if classes should be as single string or as list `"s-item__info", "clearfix"` - because `"s-item__info"` and `"clearfix"` are two classes, not one class.

Comment: what do you use to get HTML? Maybe server send different HTML for different devices  and you have to set correct User-Agent. Or maybe it send you ReCaptcha to block spamers/hacers/bots

Comment: I use a linux box with the python library requests to get the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is because before offers there is other `div` with `class="s-item__info clearfix"` but without `date, soldprice,shippingprice`.

You have to add `find` to search only in offers

```
results = soup.find('div', class_='srp-river-results clearfix').find_all("div", {"class": "s-item__info clearfix"})
```